# Не удаётся выделить текст в input при перемещении по таблице при помощи кнопок управления курсором

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, события

Всем привет! Есть таблица с множеством input type=text. Реализовал перемещение по ним при помощи клавиш управления курсором. Необходимо реализовать автоматическое выделение текста в input, при помощи эмуляции события html-события select. На данный момент этого сделать не удалось. При реальном click содержимое input выделяется. При перемещении кнопками - нет. Сначала пытался сделать через $('#input_id').select() - не получилось. Потом через bind и trigger - тоже не получилось. Что делаю не так?

**Вариант 1:**

```
$(':input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        // Пользователь нажимает на клавишу «стрелка влево»
        case 37:
            if ((parseInt(input_id) - 1) > 0 && (parseInt(input_id) - 1) < max_input_id) {
            input_id = parseInt(input_id) - 1;

            $('#' + input_id).focus(); // Перемещаем фокус на input слева

            $('#' + input_id).select(); // Пытаемся выделить текст в input
        };
    break;
    // Пользователь нажимает на клавишу «стрелка вверх»
    case 38:
        if ((parseInt(input_id) - 31) > 0 && (parseInt(input_id) - 31) < max_input_id) {
            input_id = parseInt(input_id) - 31;
            $('#' + input_id).focus();
        };
    break;
    // Пользователь нажимает на клавишу «стрелка вправо»
    case 39:
        if ((parseInt(input_id) + 1) > 0 && (parseInt(input_id) + 1) < max_input_id) {
            input_id = parseInt(input_id) + 1;
            $('#' + input_id).focus();
        };
    break;
    // Пользователь нажимает на кнопку «стрелка вниз»
    case 40:
        if ((parseInt(input_id) + 31) > 0 && (parseInt(input_id) + 31) < max_input_id) {
            input_id = parseInt(input_id) + 31;
            $('#' + input_id).focus();
        };
    break;
}
};
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
$(':input').on('keydown', function(e) {
switch(e.keyCode) {
    // Пользователь нажимает на клавишу «стрелка влево»
    case 37:
        if ((parseInt(input_id) - 1) > 0 && (parseInt(input_id) - 1) < max_input_id) {
            input_id = parseInt(input_id) - 1;

            $('#' + input_id).bind('click', function() {
                $('#' + input_id).select();
            });

            $('#' + input_id).trigger('click');
        };
    break;
    // Пользователь нажимает на клавишу «стрелка вверх»
    case 38:
        if ((parseInt(input_id) - 31) > 0 && (parseInt(input_id) - 31) < max_input_id) {
            input_id = parseInt(input_id) - 31;
            $('#' + input_id).focus();
        };
    break;
    // Пользователь нажимает на клавишу «стрелка вправо»
    case 39:
        if ((parseInt(input_id) + 1) > 0 && (parseInt(input_id) + 1) < max_input_id) {
            input_id = parseInt(input_id) + 1;
            $('#' + input_id).focus();
        };
    break;
    // Пользователь нажимает на кнопку «стрелка вниз»
    case 40:
        if ((parseInt(input_id) + 31) > 0 && (parseInt(input_id) + 31) < max_input_id) {
            input_id = parseInt(input_id) + 31;
            $('#' + input_id).focus();
        };
    break;
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно из за асинхронности работы `select` и `focus`. действие `select` срабатывает раньше... вот пример с кастылём...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var x = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id"));
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        if (x - 1 >= 0) {
          var z = x - 1;
          $('[data-id="' + z + '"]').focus();
          foo($('[data-id="' + z + '"]'));
        }
        break;

      case 38:
        if (x - 4 >= 0) {
          var z = x - 4;
          $('[data-id="' + z + '"]').focus();
          foo($('[data-id="' + z + '"]'));
        }

        break;

      case 39:

        if (x + 1 <= 8) {
          var z = x + 1;
          $('[data-id="' + z + '"]').focus();
          foo($('[data-id="' + z + '"]'));

        }

        break;

      case 40:
        if (x + 4 <= 8) {
          var z = x + 4;
          $('[data-id="' + z + '"]').focus();
          foo($('[data-id="' + z + '"]'));
        }
        break;

    };
  });

  function foo(a) {

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      a.select();
    }, 10);
  };

});
```

```css
inp
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-id="1" value="111111">
<input type="text" data-id="2" value="2222">
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.